# Flutter Login issue

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am currently developing 2 apps with Firebase and I have a doubt. I have a user and an admin. My problem is if I am using the same firebase database, will the user be able to sign up into Admin's app(Login Page) using his credentials or both app will have different authentication.(Application for login) I don't want the user logging into the admin app with user credentials and also I don't want the admin logging into the user app with user credentials. If it is possible, what can I do to avoid it?

I haven't done trying it.

(flutter ,firebase)

user can  only able to login only with user app and admin only login with admin app

Comment: Firebase Authentication has no concept of a user type, so you will have to implement that yourself on top of it. A common approach is to store an identifying value (like the email address) for each user somewhere along with their type, and then read if from there when the user (first) signs in. I've linked some questions that cover this.